# I want to know why UIImagePickerController's crop square has a slight offset, and how to fix it

Tags: ios, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, crop, photolibrary

When I pick an image from UIImagePicker with sourceType PhotoLibrary... that's a square... with allowsEditing flag set to true, the image by default sits ~18px down from where it should be

Any ideas why and how I can fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removing "View controller-based status bar appearance" key from Info.plist eliminates this bug.